# Import file mismatch errors occurs when running complete test in pytest, but passed test when run separately

Tags: python, pytest

When running the complete test with command `python -m pytest tests`, it fails with import file mismatch error.

```
import file mismatch:
imported module 'test_simplifyvcf_integrations' has this __file__ attribute:
  /home/promechpc5/Desktop/VCF-SimplifyDev/tests/test_integrations/test_simplifyvcf_integrations.py
which is not the same as the test file we want to collect:
  /home/promechpc5/Desktop/VCF-SimplifyDev/tests/testfiles/TestFullApp/test_simplifyvcf_integrations.py
HINT: remove __pycache__ / .pyc files and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Here, the errors are shown is test_simplifyvcf_integration.py, which is under tests folder. But when I run test separately with command `python -m pytest tests/test_integrations/test_simplifyvcf_integrations.py`, it pass all the test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution here is in the error message:

> and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules

you have to make sure you have unique module names inside your tests -- pytest will hoist them all into a top level namespace *unless* you add `__init__.py` files such that they are different packages

So your options are:

- rename the files which are the same
- add some `__init__.py` files

Answer (score 0):

Well this has been an issue specifically related to pytest so you shouldn't worry much about because it's only related to cached files.

step 1 remove all `__pycache__` folders from your test directory.

step 2 add the following snippet in your bashrc/zshrc file depending on which you use to stop generating those caches.

```
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
```

Comment: I would not suggest `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`, this will significantly slow all imports as they can't cache the compilation step of python